# Add properties to a superclass instance to make it becomes subclass instance

Tags: java, instance

How do I cast an instance of a class to a subclass and add properties so a ClassCastException will not be thrown? For example:

```
public class Shape {
  private int length;
  private int width;
  public Shape(int length, int width) {
    this.length = length;
    this.width = width;
  }
}
public class Solid extends Shape {
  private int height;
  public Solid (int length, int width, int height) {
    super(length, width);
    this.height = height;
  }
}
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Shape shape = new Shape(1, 2);
    //Do something to change the shape instance to solid instance.
    Solid solid = (Solid) shape;//Makes it does not throw ClassCastException.
    System.out.println(shape instanceof Solid);//Makes it print true.
    System.out.println(shape == solid);//Makes it print true.
  }
}
```

I know I can create a new instance of Solid and import the properties from the old instance, but I want to add properties to the old instance instead so comparing with == returns true. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't change the execution time type of an object once you've created it. If you want to create an instance of `Solid`, just change your first line to `new Solid(1, 2, 3)`. It's very unclear what you're trying to achieve, to be honest.

Comment: @RcExtract Please update your question to include the reason why you want to add an additional property to an existing class from an external library? Who would react on this new property when it is not defined by the original class/library? This sounds like an XY problem, maybe you should state your original problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can get close to what you want by adding a constructor to `Solid` that accepts `Shape` as an argument:

```
public Solid (Shape shape) {
    this(shape.getLength(), shape.getWidth(),0);
}
```

and test is :

```
Shape shape = new Shape(1, 2);
shape = new Solid(shape);
System.out.println(shape instanceof Solid);//prints true.
Solid solid = (Solid) shape;
System.out.println(shape == solid);//prints true.
```

Comment: I don't want the second instance to be created.

This is my situation. A program creates an instance of class A. Then, I want to add properties to it, but I cannot create a new instance of class A in the extension of the program because it should be created by the program itself. Can I add properties to the instance A created by the program without making a wrapper  class?

Comment: Another option is to use `Solid` only:  have `Solid (int length, int width)` constructor which is actually a `Shape`, and add an attribute or flag like `isSolid`